# ASP.NET Core лучше-ли делить приложение на уровни(DAL,BLL,PL)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, многие опытные разработчики используют подход, пр котором делят приложение на слабосвязанные слои.
Хочу поинтересоваться мнением Вашим по этому вопросу. Касательно ASP.NET Core.
Мне советовали делить на уровни, но при этом многие вещи придется оборачивать, а от чего-то лучше и вовсе отказаться( IdentityFramework  к примеру).

Плюсы отделения я вижу в том, случае, если слои могут быть повторно использованы, некоторое удобство при разработке большой командой, пожалуй - все.

ASP.NET Core изначально дает возможность использования сервисов, MVC делает логическое разделение(сильно связанное правда), плюс все можно использовать "из коробки"(Entity, Identity...)

Стоит-ли овчинка выделки?

Comment: А зачем от Identity отказываться?

Answer (score 1):

**В каких ситуациях нужно разбиение на проекты?**

1. Когда есть повторно используемый в разных решениях код.
2. Когда используется модульность, каждый модуль логично делать в своём проекте и независимо подключать, в особенности если модули могут писать разные люди.
3. Когда код настолько большой по объёму, что сложно разобраться что к чему если проект не разбить на максимально независимые части
4. При большом проекте который очень долго компилируется. Есть проекты которые даже на быстрых машинах компилируются по 20-30 минут, развитие таких проектов на части позволяет перекомпилировать не всё решение а только один из подпроектов, что в разы сокращает время сборки.
5. Когда есть явно отдельные части системы, которые логично выделить в отдельный модуль - проект.

Если ни один из этих пунктов не имеет место в конкретном случае, думаю что уже надо думать стоит ли создавать излишние разбиения, и это упростит систему и разработку, или наоборот её усложнит. Так как при разбиении системы на части так же придётся решать дополнительные задачи для реализации этого разбиения и его поддержки, то есть это дополнительный слой проблем.

Comment: Вы правы конечно, это общие принципы. Меня интересует ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC, там уже есть разделение + сервисы можно использовать. EntityFramework тоже выглядит как слой между базой данных и логикой.

Comment: @DennisSpade перечитал ваш вопрос, видимо я его неправильно понял, вы написали про разбиение на слои, а я ответил про разбиение на проекты

Comment: Ну да, на проекты - я думаю там разница не большая - сделать модуль внутри проекта или вынести вне. Но в целом я имею ввиду логическое разбиение.

Comment: @Dennis Очень важный вопрос в программировании это красота и удобство кода. Очень рекомендую на эту тему прочитать книгу Стива Мартина "Чистый код".

Написать несколько обёрток не так сложно, но если это поможет кода стать более понятным, интуитивным и чистым, тогда это стоит того, так как вы сэкономите много кода/времени на переработке кода.

Я не говорю о том надо их делать или нет, это решать каждому программисту команде в каждой ситуацией самому. И лучше всего это решать не на основе потому что так все делают, а на основе своего понимания зачем это нужно или не нужно.

Comment: Но я скажу, что если введение понятных слоёв сделает для вас код более понятным, простым, логичным, тогда это пойдёт только в плюс. Слои в данном случае я рассматриваю как некоторую практику которая помогает упростить код, его понимание, его поддерживание и его разработку. Если слои вам в этом помогаю, то используйте. Если слои наоборот разбивают ваш код, тогда лучше найти другое решение.

И это решение надо принимать не по вопросу использовать ли мне слои вообще или нет, а возможно по каждому слою конкретно.

Comment: @Dennis хотел сначала ответом сделать, но передумал, сам пока писал по новому понимал эти вещи, и вам спасибо за вопрос, сам давно хотел разобраться с этой темой.

Comment: По идее да, введение слоя - просто отделение от логики - это достаточно понятно, меня смущают сложности с EntityFramework, IdentityFramework - их приходится оборачивать, дублировать. Хотя в своем роде они уже играют роль обертки(про EntityFramework),

Comment: Нашел информацию на ресурсе METANIT(на русском все же удобнее понимать) - сделал трехслойную классическую архитектуру - но вот удобнее никак не стало, Identity не реализовал, остальные модели повторяются во многом. Использовал Generic Repository - хотя подключение одно и с EntityFramework все отлично работает - нет необходимости. Не совсем мне понятна обертка UnitOfWork, так как DBContext тоже обертка своего рода. Как бы там ни было - информации по этим темам мало и в англоязычных ресурсах тоже.